# MySQL query, storing a bit of calculated data just for life of query

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query

```
SELECT
    (m.speed *  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, m.arrival, m.departure) ) AS distance_traveled,
    (m.origin_x + distance_traveled) AS new_x,
    (m.origin_y + distance_traveled) AS new_y,
    m.city_id
FROM missions AS m
WHERE
        (new_x >= 1 AND new_x <= 15)
    AND
        (new_y >= 1 AND new_y <= 15)
```

Is there any way to use `distance_traveled` as a sort of variable just for this query? I wouldn't want to calculate the same math every time it is needed in the same query.

This query currently outputs the error

```
Unknown column 'distance_traveled' in 'field list'
```

Thanks!

Comment: I’d think the MySQL optimizer is able to understand the query as posted by Sebas in their answer well enough to not actually calculate the same value three times. If you need to do this query on a regular basis, then you might want to think about putting the results into extra columns though (with values calculated on INSERT/UPDATE of a record), and put an index/indexes on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not offer a solution for the `from` clause that is convenient, reliable, and efficient.  A subquery ends up getting materialized.  Variables are unreliable.

It does, however, extend the `having` clause for this case.  So, you can replace the `where` with `having` and do:

```
SELECT (m.speed *  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, m.arrival, m.departure) ) AS distance_traveled,
       (m.origin_x + (m.speed *  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, m.arrival, m.departure) )
       ) AS new_x,
       (m.origin_y + (m.speed *  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, m.arrival, m.departure) )
       ) AS new_y,
       m.city_id
FROM missions  m
HAVING (new_x >= 1 AND new_x <= 15) AND
       (new_y >= 1 AND new_y <= 15)
```

Comment: _“you can replace the `where` with `having`”_ – that deserves a word of caution about possible performance implications though.

Comment: @CBroe . . . Please elaborate.  For this query, I don't see any obvious performance implications.

Comment: Well HAVING is more likely to use a temp file for a large number of records (in the table, not necessarily in the result), right?

Answer (score 1):

Mysql still does not implement constant table expressions, therefore we need to go old school for this one:

```
SELECT
    m.distance_traveled,
    m.new_x,
    m.new_y,
    m.city_id
FROM (
        SELECT 
            `missions`.*, 
            (speed *  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, arrival, departure)) AS distance_traveled,
            (speed *  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, arrival, departure)) + origin_x AS new_x,
            (speed *  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, arrival, departure)) + origin_y AS new_y
        FROM `missions`
    ) m
WHERE
    m.new_x >= 1 AND m.new_x <= 15
AND
    m.new_y >= 1 AND m.new_y <= 15
```

Comment: Very odd ..  thanks! You would think this would make the query a little slower.

Comment: @josh MySQL *might* optimize it so that it is only calculated once, but yes, it does end up being rather verbose.

Comment: Note:  MySQL (although not other databases) will materialize the subquery, resulting in a performance penalty.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff. Please define materialize in this context? I'm curious.

Comment: @Sebas . . . MySQL has a tendency to run subqueries and store them in temporary tables.  The optimizer has been getting better in more recent versions, so it does not always do it.  But, in general in MySQL, subqueries incur the cost of writing and then reading the data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for this explanation. By Temporary Table, do you mean hard drive or memory based? Also, I'm using mysql 5.5 in my production environment. Do you happen to know if later versions are faster in this regard?

Comment: @Sebas . . . By default, I'm pretty sure MySQL puts tables, temporary tables, and materialized subqueries on disk (not 100% sure, though).  5.6 and 5.7 have further optimizations.  You might want to ask a question on dba.stackexchange.com about whether switching over is appropriate for your queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can get away with this session variable trick, but opinions on how reliable  they are varies widely:

Edit: As another answer made me notice, the result fields are being used in the WHERE, it might be safe in a HAVING, but even then I would no longer suggest it just to make your query shorter.

Edit#2: Since there were so many comments, I hesitate to delete the answer; instead I will add inline comments to show what is wrong.

```
SELECT
    @someVar := (m.speed *  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, m.arrival, m.departure) ) AS distance_traveled,
    (m.origin_x + @someVar) AS new_x,
    (m.origin_y + @someVar) AS new_y,
    m.city_id
FROM missions AS m
WHERE
        (new_x >= 1 AND new_x <= 15) // Referencing aliases from the SELECT
    AND                              // is not allowed; those values are not
        (new_y >= 1 AND new_y <= 15) // actually determined until after the 
                                     // WHERE is evaluated. Even if that 
                                     // were not the case, crossing clauses
                                     // with session variables (which this 
                                     // effectively does) is a recipe for 
                                     // disaster.
;
```

Comment: This is *very* dangerous.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `select` clause.

Comment: I was going to mention what you just edited in … Even the manual says on this subject, [_“As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement.”_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html) – so I think that is an “anything could happen”-type of warning.

Comment: It doesn't guarantee it, but it has been left to right for the 10 years I've been working with it. But, to add to my disclaimer above; I find they are safe as long as VIEWs are not involved and you do not cross clauses (ex. don't reference the same one in SELECT and WHERE).

Comment: There is can also some indeterminate behavior if you are doing strange things like changing their values in CASE WHEN conditions.

Comment: @Uueerdo . . . You have been lucky.  There are cases when it is not left-to-right.  I have seen questions on Stack Overflow where this is the very problem.

Comment: _“but it has been left to right for the 10 years I've been working with it”_ – that might as well be; but it could _change_ at any moment with a new version. So figuring out how important the feature is, and what it would matter should it “break over night” is to be at least considered.

Comment: @CBroe MySQL can change defined behavior at any moment, they have in the past.